# WebAPI 500 internal server error, not calling api method

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

So, I'm making some WebAPI based application and I have a problem when calling API method for login. Here are the code of both of the methods, server and client side.
Server side:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login(LoginVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest("bad-data");
    }

    bool isValid = false;
    int roleId = 0;

    using (var db = new FoodOrderingContext())
    {
        if (db.Users.Any(x => x.UserName.Equals(model.Username) && x.Password.Equals(model.Password)))
        {
            isValid = true;
            roleId = db.Users.First(x => x.UserName.Equals(model.Username)).RoleId;
        }
    }

    if (!isValid)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(roleId.ToString());
}
```

Client side:

```
public int Login(string usr, string pass)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52407/");
        LoginVM model = new LoginVM(usr, pass);
        var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<LoginVM>("api/account/Login", model);
        postTask.Wait();

        var result = postTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried making breakpoints, but to no avail. Code does not enter the server side method at all. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the route is ../api/account/Login and not ../api/Login?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, I'm sure. I tried it with api/login, but I got "not found" error as the result. Again, api method was not called.

Comment: Turn on break on all CLR exceptions and debug to see where it is throwing an error.

Comment: @Crowcoder The problem is the application does not break at all, I'm just not being able to login.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error it will break if you turn it on in the exception settings. This is a way to see where an exception is thrown if it is otherwise swallowed. I'm betting it will break somewhere in the pipeline before it even gets to your controller.

Comment: @Crowcoder Nope, nothing. Still not breaking anywhere, still I'm getting the InternalServerError as the text in my message box.

Comment: Are you attached to the server side app with the debugger? Unless it is just returning a result of that type somewhere it should be throwing an exception.

Comment: @Crowcoder Both client and server parts are in one Visual Studio solution. I start by turning on the server side and turning on the client side afterwards (by turning I mean right click -> Debug -> Start new instance). I assume both of the sides are available to debugger. At least they were on my previous example works.

Comment: What you want to do is [set multiple startup projects instead.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2017#BKMK_Start_multiple_projects_in_a_solution)

Comment: @Crowcoder Now they both start together, which is great, but the app does not break, nor can I read anything except for InternalServerError. Yes, I've turned on all CLR exceptions.

Comment: then I'm skeptical that your client is calling that instance of the server. Are you sure you have the port correct? If you put a simple GET action in a controller can you hit it with a browser request?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yup, just tested it from both the browser and WPF application. Simple GET request works with no problem whatsoever. POST method still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the Windows Application event log. Unhandled exceptions are logged there. Also, if custom errors are turned off (as they should be in debug mode) then you should get an error message in the body of the HTTP 500 response.

Comment: The only other idea I have, and I don't know exactly what it might tell you, is to use a tool like Postman to make that POST and see what happens.

Comment: Side note: it looks like you're storing passwords in plain-text in the database. If this is going to be a project open to the public, make sure you change that. Here's a random site I found (there are many) that describes how to store passwords securely: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: Try a POST method that passes a primitive type such as a string. If that works, then I would suspect that your service is not expecting JSON, possibly initializing to expect XML. A setting on the server that might help reveal information about the error: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;`  Also, with your breakpoints on the server-side, are they staying solid red, or switching to a hollow red circle? If debugging both client and server, I recommend separate VS instances.

Comment: I found the solution. I needed the extra route in WebApiConfig file. Once I added that, it worked like a charm. Thank you all for your help, cheers!

Comment: what exactly the exception you are getting? Why you are using ActionName? use route attribute instead of it